# Docker build error when running separate builds in parallel using different tabs in terminal and --content (mac os)

Tags: docker, build

Here is a video version of question: (so you can see error live)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/35beu44guclysk1/docker_issue.mov?dl=0

Here is a text version of question

I have the following script that I am running on mac os 13.1 on mac book pro m1 max (Docker version 20.10.21). The version of docker on the server that I am building it on is Docker version 20.10.22 (using `--context`)

```
ttab build_and_deploy_web_1.sh
ttab build_and_deploy_web_2.sh
ttab build_and_deploy_web_3.sh
ttab build_and_deploy_web_4.sh
ttab build_and_deploy_web_1_backup.sh
ttab build_and_deploy_web_2_backup.sh
```

Inside each of these scripts is this (only difference in each would be context and some servers might have an extra container.

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker --context php-pos-web-2 build --platform=linux/amd64 -t common/postfix ../common/postfix
docker --context php-pos-web-2 compose build
docker --context php-pos-web-2 compose up -d
```

Randomly during the build process, one or more of the tabs will fail with this error message:

```
[+] Building 8.0s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                5.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                5.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: no active session for skr0tc1lbhw715v7barh4o73e: context deadline exceeded
```

If I run each of these scripts sequentially I don't get the error.

What does this error mean and is there anyway I solve this?

I know I could use docker swarm for something like this, but I don't want to maintain a registry and this solution is almost perfect if the tabs didn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and the reason is docker buildkit parallelization feature that cannot effectively manage I/O bound build in parallel.

I had mutiple frontend projects that are fetching lot of small files with the `npm install` command.

I have solved with an hack: single Dockerfile, multistage build for a docker compose, and a file that act as a dependency between projects to run sequentially frontend stages.

Comment: I did DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 works! Is this an ok solution for now? Do you think docker will fix?

Comment: If your build script compiles, it does not use new features introduced in docker buildkit. This is definitely a solution for you in this moment.

I'm following parallelization issues and configurations on builkit's project but I think that will not appear relevant updates in the short terms.

Answer (score 0):

I've got previously different issues running multiple docker build processes simultaneously. Eventually I decided to use [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) which does an image build isolated in container.